# Trying to connect node with firebase, "Expected first argument to collection()"

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Getting this "Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, ' +" after trying to run this code

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"
import { getFirestore, collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore/lite'

const firebaseConfig = {
    //Config info...
}
console.log(firebaseConfig)
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);

async function getUsers(db) {
  const usersCol = collection(db, 'Users');
  const usersSnapshot = await getDocs(usersCol);
  const usersList = usersSnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
  return usersList;
}
export default getUsers()
console.log(getUsers(db))
```

Comment: `export default getUsers()`  You're trying to call your function here with an undefined `db` argument. I think you want `export default getUsers` (no `()`)

Comment: I tried that and am now getting "Request failed with error: Forbidden
    at FetchConnection.performRPCRequest"

Comment: Double check your `firebaseConfig` data or Firestore rule. It will also help if you put your full error message in your question.